# How to find unique words from file linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

i have  a big file, teh lines look like this
Text numbers etc. [Man-(some numers)] is lot of this Man-somenumbers is repeat in few lines, i want to count only unique Mans -words. I cant use unique file , because text before Man words is always different in each line.
How can i count only unique Man-somenumbers  words in file ?

Comment: A combination of `grep` and `wc` or `lc` should be a good start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, then

```
grep -oE 'Man-[0-9]+' filename | sort | uniq -c
```

should do the trick. It works as follows: First

```
grep -oE 'Man-[0-9]+' filename
```

isolates all words from the file that match the `Man-[0-9]+` regular expression. That list is then piped through `sort` to get the sorted list that `uniq` requires, and then that sorted list is piped through `uniq -c` to count how often each unique `Man-` word appears.

Comment: It worked without -o option also. When used -o option it said invalid option. I am using windows and using the commands inside GIT BASH from GIT installation.